# Obtener un escalar en java

Tags: java, sql

Como puedo leer un escalar desde java en sql server ? Esta es mi consulta a la base de datos el insert sirve perfectamente pero no se como leer la segunda instrucción

```
insert into Category values('Recursos Humanos','HR')
SELECT @@IDENTITY as insertado
```

Intento hacer lo siguiente en java

```
res=stmt.executeQuery("SELECT @@IDENTITY AS insertado");
int id=res.getInt("insertado");
System.out.println("ID insertado: "+id);
```

Pero marca excepcion por que no encuentra la columna alguna otra idea de como leer este dato ?  gracias

Comment: A ver si entiendo bien, lo que quieres es obtener el ID del ultimo registro que insertas? Podrías explicar cual es el objetivo?

Comment: Tu problema es que el `ResultSet` no ha leído ninguna fila del resultado. Siempre debes llamar a `ResultSet#next` antes de consumir la información.

Comment: Si, lo que intento es obtener el ultimo id insertado en mi base de datos para renombrar  un archivo con ese id y evitar que se dupliquen al copiarlos a mi servidor. Ya lo he conseguido gracias por responder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con esto

```
...
ResultSet res=stmt.executeQuery("SELECT @@IDENTITY AS insertado");
if (res.next() ) {  
  int id = res.getInt(1);  
}
System.out.println("ID insertado: "+ Integer.toString(id));
```

Comment: Gracias me funciono perfecto